# How to change the default mode of transportation for work/home in Google Maps Go tab?

Tags: ios, google-maps

When you set your home and work settings in Google Maps, it will automatically add them as defaults under the Go tab on iOS. If you add pinned locations, they appear underneath the Home and Work locations.

Home and Work are defaulting to driving directions whereas pinned locations use whatever method of transportation you chose when you pinned them.

How do I change the method of transportation for the home or work locations under the Go tab?

Answer (score 1):

In an ideal world, you would be able to change the method of transport for home/work. Whenever you look at the Go tab, it would then show you the fastest way to get there from your current location. Unfortunately this is not possible.

The best workaround is to pin specific routes to home/work. If maps sees that home/work has a pinned route, it replaces the default driving directions row. Initially this makes it seem like it’s the solution. However there are several disadvantages to this workaround:

1. The starting location is hardcoded. So you must pin the most common starting points.
2. The exact route is hard coded. So if there are 3 viable train options to get from A to B, you’re forced to pin all 3.
3. There is no start directions button on the row.